# MongoDB c# retrieve all the matching elements in an array within a document using Definition builder

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a document that looks like this in structure with nested sub document

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("50419077c2e6a1e18a489a0f"),
   "user":"Jone Doe",
   "fooArray":[  
      {  
         "plot":"circle",
         "color":"yellow",
      },
      {  
         "plot":"circle",
         "color":"red",
      },
      {  
         "plot":"square",
         "color":"green",
      }
   ]
}
```

And I want to retrieve all the matching elements in fooArray in this document that has circular plot.

This is what I tried

```
var filter = FilterBuilder.filter.Eq(doc => doc.User, User);
var projection = ProjectionBuilder
                .Exclude(doc => doc.Id)
                .Exclude(doc => doc.User)
                .Include(doc => doc.FooArray)
                .ElemMatch(x => x.FooArray, y => y.Plot == "circle");

var definition = new OperationDefinitions<ShapeDocument> { Filter = filter };
            return await Performer.Perform(definition, async (def, collection) =>
            {
                var findResult = collection.Find(def.Filter).Project(projection);

                var result = await findResult.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
            });
```

This is what I get

```
{  
   "fooArray":[  
      {  
         "plot":"circle",
         "color":"yellow",
      }
   ]
}
```

But it only gives me the first matching element instead of all the elements that have the plot equals to circle

```
{  
   "fooArray":[  
      {  
         "plot":"circle",
         "color":"yellow",
      },
      {  
         "plot":"circle",
         "color":"red",
      }
   ]
}
```

I did read the mongodb documentation which mentions

" The $elemMatch operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the $elemMatch condition."

Not quite sure how to achieve this!

Answer (score 6):

The question doesn't fully describe the use case so I've come up with a few potential options for you to explore based on a few assumptions, in particular they depend on LINQ being available and to be targetting a single document at a time (and that you probably don't want more code than you really need):

1) A variation on what you have. Use a standard `find` with a projection and LINQ expression.

```
var projection = Builders<ShapeDocument>.Projection
    .Expression(x => x.fooArray.Where(y => y.plot == "circle"));

var items1 = collection
    .Find(x => x.user == "Jone Doe")
    .Project(projection)
    .ToList();
```

2) Use the aggregation pipeline (you could use the same projection as above)

```
var pipeline = collection
    .Aggregate()
    .Match(x => x.user == "Jone Doe")
    .Project(i => new
            {
                x = i.fooArray.Where(x => x.plot == "circle")
            });

var items2 = pipeline.SingleOrDefault();
```

3) Pull the document back with all array elements then filter locally using LINQ. On the plus side this is a small amount of readable code, however, it does bring the entire document back before filtering. Depending on your exact use this may well be acceptable.

```
var items3 = collection.AsQueryable()
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.user == "Jone Doe")
    .fooArray.Where(x => x.plot == "circle");
```

If LINQ *really* isn't an option then there's an example [here](https://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/162anqjawb/how-to-use-new-filter-in-c) that shows how you might convert the projection to not us LINQ. Totally untested but would be something along the lines of:

```
var filter = new BsonDocument {
 {"input", "$items"},
 {"as", "item" },
 {"cond", new BsonDocument {
     // Fill in the condition values
     { "", new BsonArray { "", xxx } } }
   }
 };

var project = new BsonDocument {
 { "items", new BsonDocument { { "$filter", filter} } }
};

var pipeline = collection.Aggregate().Project(project);
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a sweet and simple solution using [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) which is just a wrapper library for the c# driver.

```cs
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class User : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Foo[] Foos { get; set; }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string Plot { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            var user = new User
            {
                Name = "Jone Doe",
                Foos = new[]
                {
                    new Foo{ Plot = "circle", Color="yellow"},
                    new Foo{ Plot = "circle", Color="red"},
                    new Foo{ Plot = "square", Color="green"},
                }
            };

            user.Save();

            var circularFoos = DB.Collection<User>()
                                 .Where(u => u.Name == "Jone Doe")
                                 .SelectMany(u => u.Foos)
                                 .Where(f=>f.Plot=="circle").ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the aggregate query it generates:

```
  {
    "$match": {
      "Name": "Jone Doe"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$Foos"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "Foos": "$Foos",
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "Foos.Plot": "circle"
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can just as well do that without that library by just using the IQueryable  `var circularFoos = collection.AsQueryable().Where(u => u.user == "Jone Doe").SelectMany(u => u.fooArray).Where(f => f.plot == "circle").ToArray();` like Greg Stanley said.

Comment: true but once i got used to the conveniences this library provides, there was no going back. now i wouldn't touch the official driver with a 10ft pole ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I figured a neat way to do it

```
var filter = FilterBuilder.filter.Eq(doc => doc.User, User);
var definition = new OperationDefinitions<ShapeDocument> { Filter = filter };
return await Performer.Perform(definition, async (def, collection) =>
{
var findResult = collection.Find(def.Filter).Project(doc => doc.fooArray.Where(x => x.Plot == "Circle"));
var result = await findResult.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```